# Conditional join in pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

I am merging 2 datasets liek this:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left' on='ID')
```

I only want to select records where df2.NAME='ABC'

What is the quckest way to do this? In SQL, it would be:

```
select * from df1 left join df2 on df1.id=df2.id and df2.name='ABC'
```

Comment: df1.merge(df2,how='left' on='ID').query("name=='ABC'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1.merge(df2[df2.NAME=='ABC'], how='left', on='ID')
```

or

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')
df = df[df.NAME=='ABC']
```

depending on whether you want these rows to exist in the resulting df (with NaNs) [snippet 1] or for them to be dropped entirely [snippet 2].